# Protractor - Getting error "Cannot find module ../lib/cli.js

Tags: node.js, protractor

I've been working with Protractor for a couple days now, but ran into a problem today on my work machine with node.  So I tried doing a 'brew uninstall node', but hit an error, and since then have not been able to get my protractor tests to run.

I've gone through many steps, including removing node manually and reinstalling, as well as attempting to reinstall protractor.  Currently, the error I'm getting when I try to run any of my tests is 'Cannot find module ../lib/cli.js'.

I verified that I have a 'protractor' directory in ~/.node/lib/node_modules, and there is a 'cli.js' file in that folder's 'lib' directory.  I've tried installing protractor globally, so there is also the same 'protractor' folder in /usr/local/lib/node_modules, and it too has a lib folder that contains a 'cli.js' file.  I've also tried installing a 'node_modules' folder into my project directory, and it too has a lib/cli.js file, so I'm not really sure where it could be missing that file.

I'm running OS X 10.10.  If I run a 'which node' command, I get back '/usr/local/bin/node' and /usr/local/bin is in my PATH.  Also, my NODE_PATH variable points to /usr/local/lib/node_modules.

I'm not sure if this is needed for this or not, but here is one of the test cases I'm attempting to run that throws the error:

```
describe('CreateUser', function() {
    signupPage = require('./Pages/SignupPage.js');
    loginPage = require('./Pages/LoginPage.js');
    dataHelper = require('./Library/DataHelper.js');

    var ptor;
    var plistPath = '/Users/Heath/Documents/Scripts/Protractor/ProtractorFramework/TestRunData/CurrentTestRun.plist';
    var userName = dataHelper.updateUserName(plistPath);

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        //ptor = protractor.getInstance();
//      ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    });

    it('It should add new user', function() {
        browser.driver.get(loginPage.url);

        loginPage.createStudyAbroadAccountLink.click();
        signupPage.firstNameTextBox.sendKeys('blah');
        signupPage.lastNameTextBox.sendKeys('whatever');
        signupPage.emailTextBox.sendKeys(userName);

        signupPage.facultyMemberDropdownItem.click();
        signupPage.maleRadioButtonItem.click();

        signupPage.passwordTextBox.sendKeys('1-Council');
        signupPage.passwordConfirmationTextBox.sendKeys('1-Council');
        signupPage.agreeCheckbox.click();
        signupPage.signupButton.click();

        browser.sleep(6000);
//        ptor.sleep(6000);
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://www-qa.ciee.org/myaccount');
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm starting to think I'm not going to get protractor tests running on this machine again.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall `protractor` in your local (not global) node env?

Comment: Ya I had tried that, but for some reason it didn't install a 'selenium' folder with it. So you're right. That basically was the fix after I copied that directory from the global installation folder. I apologize, I didn't see your comment until I posted my own answer, but you're right enough to mark as an answer if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Well it figures.I've been working on this for 10 hours, and I found out what the issue was 5 mins after I posted. If I just called protractor without a full path it was running it from /usr/local/bin. There is a lib folder in 'local' that has a cli.js file, so that still confuses me a bit, but I tried running the test with the project's 'protractor' and received an error about not being able to start webdriver. (even though I had an instance running already)

The project's folder was missing a selenium directory, so I copied that into it, and all is working now. I'm still confused why the default protractor wasn't working, but at least I can run the tests now.

I'm pretty sure this is all due to me trying to perform a 'brew uninstall node'.  After getting an error on that command, it broke something protractor related.

Thanks,